# Getting syntax error using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

```
// Add an additional field to the checkout within a new fieldset
add_filter('eshopaddtocheckout','eshop_extras_checkout');

function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){

$echo .= '  <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $(".formGroup").hide();
            $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>';



    $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";


    $echo .= '<legend>Select the Approriate Form</legend>' . "\n";

    $echo .= ' <div id="chooseForm">
        <input type="checkbox" name="forms2[]" id="ArticlesOrderForm" value="ArticlesOrderForm"> <b>Articles Order Form </b><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forms2[]" id="PressReleasesForm"  value="PressReleasesForm"> <b> Press Releases Form </b><br>
    </div>

    <div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">
        <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
        <label for="kwd1">Art-Keywords1</label><input class="short" type="text" name="kwd1" value="" id="kwd1" maxlength="20" size="20" > <br>

    </div>

    <div id="PressReleasesForm" class="formGroup">
        <legend>Press Releases Form</legend>
        <label for="kwd2">PRKeywords2</label><input class="short" type="text" name="kwd2" value="" id="kwd2" maxlength="20" size="20"> <br>
    </div>';


 $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";

    $echo .= '<legend>Extras</legend>' . "\n";
    $echo .= '<label for="eshop_extra">'.__('Extra Field','eshop').' <span class="reqd">*</span><br />
          <input class="short" type="text" name="eshop_extra" value="" id="eshop_extra" maxlength="20" size="20" /></label><br />';
    $echo .= '</fieldset>' . "\n";

    return $echo;
}
```

```
  // Add extra field to error checks
    add_filter('eshoperrorcheckout','eshop_extras_errorcheckout');
    function eshop_extras_errorcheckout($_POST){
        $myerror='';

        if(!isset($_POST['eshop_extra']) || trim($_POST['eshop_extra'])==''){
        $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>Extra Field</strong> - missing.','eshop_extras').'</li>';
    }



    if(!isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'])) {

      if(!isset($_POST['kwd1']) || trim($_POST['kwd1'])=='') {
        $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>KWD1</strong> - missing.','kwd1').'</li>';
        }
    }


    if(!isset($_POST['PressReleasesForm'])) {

      if(!isset($_POST['kwd2']) || trim($_POST['kwd2'])=='') {
        $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>KWD2</strong> - missing.','kwd2').'</li>';
        }
    }   


        return $myerror;
    }
```

** Now iam not getting any syntax erors.... please check below link: (under select the appropriate form) , when u check them, they're missing away.. what am I doing wrong..? **

articlewritingservicess.com/shopping-cart/checkout/

Comment: `$_POST` looks like PHP to me, not jQuery

Comment: This looks like a rather messy mix of jQuery/JavaScript code and PHP. Which line does the error point to anyway?

Comment: Please post the full error line, what line is it pointing towards?

Comment: its pointing error AT:    if($('#check_id').is(":checked"))

Comment: It sounds like you set the dataType to JSON or JSONP but are returning HTML, but without code, we can only guess. Can you post the Javascript side of the code?

Comment: I just edited above, pls kindly check and tell me..

Comment: @Bob Well, which is it? Is the error happening in PHP or Javascript. I see you have removed the jQuery tag, but your latest comment suggests the error is happening in JavaScript.

Comment: @Bob, you have a serious misunderstanding of server-side vs client-side development.  You are mixing up PHP and jQuery in the same code, and it's not going to work!

Comment: @freefaller He is properly separating it for this use-case, it will work if syntactically and logically correct.

Comment: @Kevin, no he isn't... look at the 2nd `if` statement in the `eshop_extras_errorcheckout` function - it's jquery being used in PHP.  (Edit: I apologise if I've got the wrong end of the stick here, and I will happily retract my comments if I am incorrect)

Comment: @freefaller I see it now, Post that as an answer as that's clearly what is wrong.

Comment: @Bob - you have marked my answer as the correct one, so there is no need to update your question to say that the problem is resolved.  People need to see **what** that problem was in the first place, otherwise my answer makes no sense.  This is also why you're seeing lots of downvotes, because some people simply won't have seen what the your problem was, just that you don't have one anymore! Hope that makes sense

Comment: If you have another question to ask, please ask it in a new question. Please do not completely change the text of your question. There [is a meta discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152221/op-removing-question-after-answer-selected) about this question.

Comment: Please don't remove the content of your question after it has been answered.  It might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing up server-side code and client-side code.

PHP is used on the server, and will produce the HTML that is sent to the browser (that HTML can include jquery).  But the jquery will only work on the browser.

The problem is that you are using jquery commands **on the server-side**, with the following line...
(This is the 2nd `if` statement in your `eshop_extras_errorcheckout` function)

```
if($('#check_id').is(":checked"))
```

This should be PHP code, not jquery... something like...

```
if(isset($_POST('check_id'))){
  // Do something
}
```

---

**Additional based on OP's comment**

The reason that your checkboxes are not remaining "checked" on the post-back of the page is because you are creating the `<input type="checkbox"` code each time, and if you don't specifically provide the `checked` attribute, it will be unchecked when the page is displayed.

(I'm not sure if you're familiar with ASP.NET, but in that technology if you tick a checkbox and then post-back, ASP.NET will handle this for you.  PHP does not do it as standard, you need to tell it to check it.)

So, for instance, where you are "echo"ing the following line in your `eshop_extras_checkout` function (note, this is contained with a PHP string, it is not straight mark-up):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="forms2[]" id="ArticlesOrderForm"
  value="ArticlesOrderForm"> <b>Articles Order Form </b><br>
```

... you need to conditionally put the `checked` attribute, something like this:

```
(isset($_POST('ArticlesOrderForm')) ? "Checked" : "")
```

... which would result in the string looking like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="forms2[]" id="ArticlesOrderForm" 
  value="ArticlesOrderForm" ' . (isset($_POST('ArticlesOrderForm')) ? "Checked" : "") . '> <b>Articles Order Form </b><br>
```

Therefore, when the final HTML is sent to the browser, the attribute `checked` will appear if the checkbox was checked, and it won't if it won't.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: ?  This isn't even remotely true.  He is echoing out client side code using PHP.

Comment: Lol I take that back.  I scrolled down

Comment: @Andrew, have you looked at the 2nd `if` statement in the `eshop_extras_errorcheckout` function? That is jquery code in a PHP block.  I have updated my answer to make this clear

Comment: Bro, now that error has gone! BUT the checkboxes are getting dismissed as soon as I check them (donno why).. please check my modified code and my link as well!

Comment: @Bob, my guess is that you are not setting the checkbox as checked when on the post-back of the page.  I will update my answer to explain, but this is not strictly part of the original question!!

Comment: @freefaller  Thanks a lot bro! ur very helpful for me.. Have a gr8 life! :)