# Logic error in my code

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am unable to validate the textarea below, don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
 $echo .= ' <div id="chooseForm">
                <input type="checkbox" name="ArticlesOrderForm" value="ArticlesOrderForm"> <b>Articles Order Form </b>                     

            </div>';
```

```
$echo .= '  <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $(".formGroup").hide();
            $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>';
```

```
  $echo .=  '<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">
            <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
            <b><label for="article_keywords">Keywords/Titles<span class="reqd">*</span> : </label></b> <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" > </textarea>
        </div>';
```

```
if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') {  

  if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
    $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>Keywords/Titles</strong> - missing.','article_keywords').'</li>';
    }   
}
```

I should get a message 'keywords/titles - missing' if someone do not enter into that text area..

Could anyone please tell whats wrong in my logic?

Comment: and where is `ArticlesOrderForm` input/checkbox ?

Comment: @Jim, you're better off sticking with a single user account, as that way (assuming you play by the rules) you can gain positive reputation, which will help you in the long run. It's rather obvious to me that [you are the same person as the user Bob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735) that I was helping yesterday

Comment: @freefaller good detective work :)

Comment: Not really detective work @piddl0r, just when you've spent an hour pulling your hair out the day before, the coding style, the variable names, etc become rather obvious!

Answer (score 3):

You are testing the wrong conditions, instead of having

```
if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) && !empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
```

Try testing

```
if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
```

Now you're testing if it's *not* empty, while you should be testing if it *is* empty

Answer (score 1):

Youre checking whether `$_POST['article_keywords']` isn't set AND isn't empty. Those two exclude each other.

You can either remove the `empty` or the `isset` check to achieve your goal. (Or just replace the `&&` with a `||` and remove the `!` in front of `empty`)

Answer (score 1):

@Jim (or [is it Bob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735/getting-syntax-error-using-jquery)?),

Part of the problem (as well as the logic errors that other are pointing out) is because browsers do not return a value in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` for `<div>` elements.

Your HTML has `<div id="ArticlesOrderForm">`

It looks like you are trying to find if a checkbox has been selected. In which case you should do the following, *assuming* you create an `<input type="checkbox" id="ArticlesOrderForm">` where `ArticlesOrderForm` is unique within the form!!

```
if(isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'])){
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735) (and assuming you haven't changed your code) I can see that you do have an `<input type="checkbox" id="ArticlesOrderForm">` as well as `<div id="ArticlesOrderForm">`.

This is **invalid HTML** because all `id` attributes on the page **must** be unique - you cannot have the same `id` attribute on more than one element.

I still hold that to test if the checkbox was selected remains as...

```
if(isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'])){
}
```

... because the value contained in `$_POST(['ArticlesOrderForm'])` will **not** be set to `checked`.  A checkbox will only send back a value **if it has been checked**, if it has not been checked then it will NOT send back a value, and therefore `$_POST(['ArticlesOrderForm'])` will NOT be set.

But you **must** remove the `id="ArticlesOrderForm"` from the `<div>` (or call it something else) to have valid HTML.

Comment: Hello  freefaller,
as soon as I check the checkbox 'articlesorderform' , i get a textarea opened, now iam validating the 'textarea' , i tried the codes given by others, seems Iam ahving problem related to checkbox as well.. Ur saying something , BUT i didnt get that... It seems ur checking the checkbox only either for Null or not, BUT in my case , as soon as i check checkbox, textarea shud be opened, so I have written as "if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') { " so, what exactly wrong I did.. sory for my bad english..

Comment: @Jim, the HTML you are putting into `$echo` has a `<div>` with the `id="ArticlesOrderForm"`... put simply: the content of a `<div>` is NOT sent back to the browser as part of either the `$_POST` or `$_GET`. If you ALSO have a checkbox called `ArticlesOrderForm` in the HTML, then that is **invalid HTML** as all `id` attributes must be different.  If you **do** have a checkbox with `id="ArticlesOrderForm"` then the value in `$_POST` will **not** be `checked`... you should check for it with the code I have in my answer above

Comment: Hello bro, Yep! Its me Bob only! As i was unable to create another new post with my account, made me to create another new account with my brother's name.. i really have no intention to cheat anyone, situation made me to do like this.. Hop you do not misunderstand me. 

Anyway bro, yesterday i updated my code again and I really do not have same id name in 2 html elements anywhere.. please check in my post, I updated my checkbox code.. pls chk it and get rid of this another issue bro and ur very helpful for me.. :) I luv this forum vm! All Gems are sitting together..

Comment: @Jim, if your code is as you have it in your edited question, then you STILL have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute - and you are STILL checking for the checkbox in the wrong way.  Read what we're telling you, and act on it... if you don't you will continue to be frustrated that things aren't working, and we will stop helping because you're not doing what we're telling you.  There is only so much time I'm willing to spend

Comment: bro, 

 i really didnt same id in 2 places... here are the 2 line again:  <input type="checkbox" name="ArticlesOrderForm" value="ArticlesOrderForm"> <b>Articles Order Form </b>


AND

 $echo .=  '<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">

Comment: ok @Jim, but do you still have the same `if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked')` code?

Comment: YES bro, I have this: if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') { 
  
   if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
  $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>Keywords/Titles</strong> - missing.','article_keywords').'</li>';
  } 
 }

Comment: ok @Jim, you have ignored my suggestion of using `if(isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'])){` and my explanation of why you should use it, at least 3 times now. **I refuse to spend any more time helping somebody who is not listening to me, and not following my suggestions**.

Comment: No bro, pls do not msiudnerstand me...  i already tried when u asked me to try like that, i just forgetten to mention here, thats all.. BUT even that is not working bro..

I tried like these 2 ways: A) if( isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'])) { 

B) if( isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm']) ||  $_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') {


but validation not happening to my keywords/titles field..

i really didnt expected i face this much trouble for this small validation... pls suggest me bro, where actually went wrong..

please check the whole code here bro: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcqk/

Comment: here is the link to check the output: articlewritingservicess.com/shopping-cart/checkout/

Comment: iam sorry bro, i realy forgotten to mention that, pls do not misunderstoand me.. i really appreciate for trying to help me out.. :)

Comment: bro, u really not interested to help me...?

Comment: @Jim.  1) stop calling me "bro". 2) I'm in the UK, so I'm not necessarily on SO at the same time as you. 3) why do you still have `== "checked"` when I've said it won't be "checked" 4) why is `$_POST` a parameter of `eshop_extras_errorcheckout`? Are you sure that the `$_POST` collection is being passed in? Have you tried doing a `var_dump($_POST)` within the function?

Comment: actually I was able to resolve it.. from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039817/unable-to-validate-textarea/13040061#13040061  (one guy resolved my prob), it was just a space prob between opening and closing of textarea tag.. thanks a lot for ur time!

Comment: Ah, that's a good spot! Good luck with the rest of your project @Jim  :-)

Comment: another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046203/data-needs-to-be-stored-in-html-elements-automatically-before-server-validation

can u pls?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't supplied the whole form so this may or may not be your first issue.
Your first if statement is checking if a $_POST variable that doesn't seem to exist.

```
if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked')
```

You have a DIV in the form with the id 'ArticlesOrderForm' but no form input so it won't be included in $_POST. $_POST is an array of values submitted via POST from a form, it doesn't include the whole contents of the form only inputs within the form. So the first statement will always be false.

To correct this you will need a valid input with an id/name of "ArticlesOrderForm" and a value of "checked", going by the name I would assume you want a checkbox for example.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ArticlesOrderForm" value="checked" />
```

Please note that ids need to be unique so you can't have two ids with the same values, that's why I used the name attribute in my example, it will appear in $_POST as 'ArticlesOrderForm' but won't conflict with the div with id 'ArticlesOrderForm'.

After that issue you need to check you other statement as has been mentioned by the other answers to this question.

**Update**

Having looked at what is apparently another of your questions on another user : 
[Getting syntax error using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735/getting-syntax-error-using-jquery)

I can't see any form tags and the jQuery doesn't seem to try and submit the data. You should wrap the form in a `<form>` tag. Something like :

```
<form method="post" action="you_page.php">
    <!-- form fields / inputs -->
</form>
```

If this is the case you really need to brush up on your html before you start with javascript/php! Have a look at this to get you started : [HTML Forms](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/html/elements/form).

Comment: hello piddlor, could u please be bit breif on this statement "You have a DIV in the form with the id 'ArticlesOrderForm' but no form input so it won't be included in post. So the first statement will always be false. " iam sorry i didnt get exacly..  NOW WHAT YOU WANT ME TO DO.?

Comment: bro, I updated my checkbox code , could you please check into myy original post!

Comment: could you include the html for the whole form, I can't tell from what's there what's wrong. For example I can't see the form tag so I don't know if it exists or if you are using the post method.

Comment: @Jim I've updated my answer again, but you need to provide more code!

Comment: actually i just copy pasted some snippet above, I have everything what you asked above.. iam just unable to validate that, iam pretty sure iam doing wrong from above code given in my 1st post somewhere..