# Unable to validate textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am unable to validate the textarea below, don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
<div id="chooseForm">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ArticlesOrderForm" value="ArticlesOrderForm">
    <b>Articles Order Form </b>
</div>';
```

```
$echo .= '  <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            $(".formGroup").hide();
            $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
                if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
                }
            });
        });

    </script>';
```

```
     $echo .=  '<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">
                <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
                <b><label for="article_keywords">Keywords/Titles<span class="reqd">*</span> : </label></b> <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" > </textarea>
            </div>';
<br/><br/>

if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') {  

  if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
    $myerror= '<li>'.__('<strong>Keywords/Titles</strong> - missing.','article_keywords').'</li>';
    }   
}
```

I should get a message 'keywords/titles - missing' if someone does not enter into that text area..
Could anyone please tell me whats wrong in my logic?

Please find the full codes here : http://jsfiddle.net/DTcqk/3/
and here: http://jsfiddle.net/YYAbm/

Comment: also, echoing scripts not suggested

Comment: @eicto wasted bandwidth, terrible XHTML support or potential XHR attack? The last one doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Comment: @JanDvorak wasted bandwidth, unreadable code, bad habbit

Comment: ah, seems you mixing serverside and clientside scripts, you think that `if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked')` will run if you check the checkbox ? i.e. Where the post request at all ? I not see ajax or form submit here

Comment: Install Firebug into your Firefox, do whatever you see fails, and have a look at the parameters sent in the `net` tab. Your data not showing up there? Javascript fault. Data showing up? PHP fault.

Comment: BTW, you are using the wrong paste site. JSFiddle deals with HTML, CSS and Javascript. You do have PHP here! And hopefully understand the fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your textarea is not empty by default:

```
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" > </textarea>
                                                    you have space here ----^
```

So it won't enter your following `if` :

```
if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
```

You should use `trim()` if you want to catch variables with only spaces in your validation `if`, like so:

```
$_POST['article_keywords'] = trim($_POST['article_keywords']);
if(!isset($_POST['article_keywords']) || empty($_POST['article_keywords'])) {
```

Comment: wow brother, U made my day! U donno how much I was hitting to a wall since many hrs.. i was really unable to find that small space between that.. Anyway now its working, Ur genious.. Thanks a lot bro! Have  a gud day :)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'checked') {
```

with

```
if($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm'] == 'ArticlesOrderForm') {
```

The input type checkbox does not post "checked" it posts the value attribute of the checkbox.

Comment: no bro, still not working after trying with ur line..

Comment: Bro, i didnt get this: The input type checkbox does not post "checked" it posts the value attribute of the checkbox. 

Means what I have to do..?

Comment: It means when you're checking the posted value of ArticlesOrderForm, you need to check for the value of the checkbox, which was "ArticlesOrderForm" instead of checking for the string "checked".

Comment: Also as @Nelson mentioned, you need to make sure there's no spaces in your textarea, either remove the space or `trim` $_POST['article_keywords'] before you check to see if it's `empty`.