# data needs to be stored in html elements automatically before server validation occurs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I just had one doubt:

I have a form where I do server side validation.. i have np with validation, BUT the prob is:

In a Form, assume I entered some 9 fields (instead of 10 ), it shows me an erros saying that '10th field missing' and all the data I entered in 9 fields has to be re-entered again.. (sometimes its really damn tough to re-enter same data because of small mistake )

so, aim thinking that whatever the data entered previously in textfield or textarea or some other html element, it should be saved automatically even after server validation does.. so that user need not re-type again..

how can I achive this.. I tried in google, but didnt understood how to search for this kind of sittuation and i did not find any solution yet..

sory for my bad english.. Hope u udnerstood my prob..

so, any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jim, this is the same situation as in [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014735/getting-syntax-error-using-jquery).
(Before anybody points out that it is a different account, it's the same actual person - long story!)

PHP will not keep the "state" of the control when you send it back to the browser after a post-back.

So instead of sending back the following each and every time...

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext">
```

You need to send back what was originally entered as part of the control...

```
<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext"
   value="<?php echo $_POST['mytext']; ?>>
```

With checkboxes and radios (which was your original question), you need something like...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" name="mycheck"
   value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['mycheck']) ? "checked" : ""); ?>>
```

And as you're talking about `<textarea>` controls, you'd do something like...

```
<textarea id="mytext" name="mytext"><?php echo $_POST['mytext']; ?></textarea>
```

---

**Update**

As you are building the HTML into the `$echo` string variable (rather than just having the HTML mark up directly), you need to include the above code **as part of the string**.

If you do an `echo` command **during** the building of the string, the thing being `echo`ed will be sent to the screen straight away.  Then when you send the contents of `$echo` via the command `echo $echo;` you get everything else.

So, for a single line textbox you would do...

```
$echo = '<input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" value="'. $_POST['mytext'] .'">';
```

For a checkbox you would do...

```
$echo = '<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" name="mycheck" '. (isset($_POST['mycheck']) ? "checked" : "") .'>';
```

For a multi line textbox you would do....

```
$echo = '<textarea id="mytext" name="mytext">'. $_POST['mytext'] . '</textarea>';
```

So you see that we are including the existing value of the control as part of the string that you are building.

Comment: For TEXTAREA -- When I used this :


 

  $echo .=  '<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">
         <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
         <b><label for="article_keywords">Keywords/Titles<span class="reqd">*</span> : </label></b> <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" ><?php echo $_POST["article_keywords"]; ?></textarea>
         <b><label for="article_keywordDensity">Keyword Density (Optional): </label></b>  <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywordDensity" name="article_keywordDensity" ></textarea>         
       </div>';

Comment: iam seeing this value inside my textarea :  <?php echo $_POST["article_keywords"]; ?>  

when I used above code.. anything wrong in my above code.?

Comment: pls check the output here: articlewritingservicess.com/shopping-cart/checkout/  (after clicking checkbox 'articlesorderform' )

Comment: Sorry @Jim, I forgot you "echo" everything out (which is a silly way to do it).  Use your head... if you can't use `<?php...?>` commands WITHIN a string, how do you get around it?  Look at the answer I gave you on your original question

Comment: iam not a php coder actually :( BUT i need to do this.. I have no option.. 

please see the code in below comment (iam getting weird result), pls chk output in that above link..

Comment: $echo .=  '<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">
         <legend>Articles Order Form</legend>
         <b><label for="article_keywords">Keywords/Titles<span class="reqd">*</span> : </label></b> <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" >';
         
          <?php echo $_POST["article_keywords"]; ?>
         
 $echo .=  </textarea>
         <b><label for="article_keywordDensity">Keyword Density (Optional): </label></b>  <textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywordDensity" name="article_keywordDensity" ></textarea>         
       </div>';

Comment: @Jim - it's pretty obvious you're not a php coder (or a coder in general!). That won't work because you are building a string, and then echoing directly out to the page in the middle, then echoing the string later on.  I will update my answer *yet again* with what you should do

Comment: wow! It works like a charm now! BUT 2 small issues:

a) Assume I checked box for 'articlesorderform' adn I didnt enter any other imp field, when it got refreshed, there is a 'tick' mark for my checkbox 'articlesodrerform', BUT its functionality working... I mean when there is a tickmark, 2 textareas shud open actyally... I guess its related to Jquery issue, could u pls look code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LGDXb/


b) there is some space beginning of text area..

Comment: @Jim, remember, if the HTML controls need to be a particular state when sent from the PHP to the browser, then you must code the PHP for those control to be in that state.  Just because you change their state via javascript/jquery on the browser does NOT mean they will still be in the same state on the post-back. You've already seen that with the missing text in the `<textarea>`, is the same principle.  If a control need to be visible, write the code in the PHP to make it visible *if it needs to be, based on the information passed back from the page*

Comment: Got it! BUT how? I mean, it needs a lot of coding stuff..? Do you think I can do it easily with my present code..?

Comment: From what I can tell, if you change `<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup">` into `<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup" style="display:' . (isset($_POST['ArticlesOrderForm']) ? "" : "none") . '">` that will show/hide the div section based on the checkbox value (but it will be hidden the first viewing of the page)

Comment: Sorry @Jim, finishing for the day. As I say, if you make things visible/hidden as part of javascript, you need to replicate the state via PHP. You'll have to figure that out youself, or start a new question. I have answered your original one, so it would make sense to mark this question as answered.  The amount of time I'm giving you, I think I deserve something in return  ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for your precious time :) i try to create another post on this.. , BTW, any suggestion for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053743/how-to-create-similar-website-designs-in-an-easy-way

Comment: any suggestion here pls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058013/need-to-design-my-theme-css-similar-to-other-site

Comment: I will be really glad if you would tell me how to do this: "As I say, if you make things visible/hidden as part of javascript, you need to replicate the state via PHP. You'll have to figure that out youself,"

Unfortunately, i have got all -ve points becoz of my stupid queries, i dont have a chance to create another topic as well)

if u just able to help me , after doing validation, whatever chebox is checked, its respective textareas shud also display (no matters how many times page refreshed..) if i explictly uncehck and check, iam able to see its belongings (ie., 2 text areas)..

Comment: I'm sorry @Jim, I am NOT going to do the work for you - if you're going to be a developer, you need to be able to figure out stuff like this for yourself. Think about it: if your create HTML, then send the HTML to the browser, change the state of objects on the browser and post information back to the server - you need to send the new HTML back to the browser with the elements in those changed states.  I've already given you an example... I really cannot justify giving you any more time

Comment: atleast any sample code (with 1 or 2 html elements),, so atleast by seeieng that I will try... or any link or tutorial on these..? even iam not understanding what to search in google for this kinda..

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be

```
<div id="ArticlesOrderForm" class="formGroup"> 
<legend>Articles Order Form</legend> 
<b><label for="article_keywords">Keywords/Titles<span class="reqd">*</span> : </label></b> 
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywords" name="article_keywords" ><?php echo $_POST["article_keywords"]; ?></textarea> 
<b><label for="article_keywordDensity">Keyword Density (Optional): </label></b> 
<textarea rows="6" cols="50" id="article_keywordDensity" name="article_keywordDensity" ></textarea>
```

But why not use JavaScript validation?

This jQuery Plugin is pretty awesome and easy to use:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

You add the validation type by simply adding classes like required or email.

Comment: Never rely on javascript/jquery validation alone - it's a "nice to have" for user interaction, but can easily be bypassed.  You MUST have server-side validation

Comment: He states, he already has a php side validation. His only problem is that the fields that are correct, dont get refilled once the page is reloaded. This could perfectly be solved by javascript validation.

Comment: Your answer is written in such a way that it suggest that javascript validation is an alternative, not an addition.  It is NOT a "perfect solution" because should the browser not have javascript enabled, you still need to pre-populate the control values (as you suggest in the first part of your answer). I think it's a case of bad wording